# Restrict function template for member functions only

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am working in C++11 and have the following code that compiles. But the problem is that the function `func` in the below example can also be called with a `std::function`, lambda, pointer to a function etc.

Instead, I want that `func` should only be called by a pointer to a non-static member function of any class. That is, I want to restrict this function only member function pointers.

```
template <typename Callable, typename... Args> void func(Callable&& callable, Args&&... args)
{

}
struct Test
{
    int someMember(int x) 
    { 
        return x; 
    }
};
void g(int, int, int) 
{

}
int main()
{
    func(g, 1, 1, 1);     //this works currently but it should be rejected in the modified program
    func([](int){}, 42);  //this works currently but it should be rejected in the modified program 
    
    Test test;
    func(&Test::someMember, test, 1);// this works currently and should work in the modified version
}
```

As we can see in the above program, all of the calls to `func` works. But I want that only the call `func(&Test::someMember, test, 1);` should work and the other two calls should be rejected.

So how can I achieve this. Maybe there is a way to use SFINAE or some other metaprogramming technique.

Comment: Why is this restriction desirable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by setting up the template parameters in such a way that only pointers to member function are accepted(as shown below). In particular, we can have 4 template parameters corresponding to the class, member function parameters, object of that class and finally the arguments passed to that member function.

```
template<typename className, typename... Param,typename Ret, typename... Args>  
void func(Ret (className::*ptrFunc)(Param... param),className& Object, Args... args)
{
    (Object.*ptrFunc)(args...); //std::invoke(ptrFunc, Object, args...) in C++17
}
int main()
{
    Test test;
    func(&Test::someMember, test, 1);//only this form works now  
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YxnTehe86)

Comment: Wow, absolutely ingenious.

Answer (score 5):

I think `static_assert` (with [`std::is_member_function_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer)) is the perfect tool for the situation. No need to change the signature of `func`, and the error message can be whatever you want, so it's clearer than, for example, a substitution failure.

To call `callable`, you may use [`std::mem_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn).

```
template <typename Callable, typename... Args>
void func(Callable callable, Args&&... args)
{
    static_assert(std::is_member_function_pointer<Callable>::value, "callable must be a member function");

    std::mem_fn(callable)(args...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3971nhT6E)

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe there is a way to use SFINAE or some other metaprogramming technique.

That would do it, since we have [`std::is_member_function_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer).

```
template <typename Callable, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_member_function_pointer<Callable>::value, void>::type
func(Callable callable, Args&&... args)
{

}
```

If the predicate is false, enable_if produces no type, and our template has no return type, making the function non-viable.

The change to pass by value is because it makes to controlling condition simpler, and because we are only passing pointers to members (fairly cheap to copy).