# How to accept only callable objects in templates except pointer to data members?

Tags: c++, templates, invoke, template-specialization, callable-object

I want to create a templated function which accepts and invokes a callable object(except pointer to data members) with arguments to pass to it.
I want the template to only accept the following types:-

1. Pointers to functions
2. Pointers to member functions
3. Lambda
4. bind expressions
5. std::function
6. Functors

**Like this...**

```
template< class Function, class... Args >
explicit X( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
```

But the first argument is accepting any type and I want to create some validation such that it only accept callable objects and throw error(preferably in compile-time) if it invalidates.

Comment: Have you looked at [std::is_invocable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) ? See the examples at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @RichardCritten -- pointer-to-data-member is invocable.

Comment: Copy/pasted from [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74940437/restrict-function-template-for-member-functions-only). Just the opposite is asked which is trivial.

Comment: Reopened. The claimed duplicate asks about restricting a template to **member functions only**. This question is about allowing all callable types except pointer-to-member-data.

Answer (score 3):

There's a C++20 concept just for this purpose:

```
template<class Function, class... Args>
    requires (std::invocable<Function, Args...>
        && !std::is_member_object_pointer_v<Function>)
void X(Function&& f, Args&&... args);
```

(Edited to add `is_member_object_pointer_v` due to comments below.)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. I haven't paid attention recently, so some more recent standard may have stepped on the meaning of "callable object", but back when all this was first introduced, a pointer-to-data-member was a callable object, hence, invocable. The question asks how to exclude pointer-to-data-member.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Please show an example of what you're talking about on http://godbolt.org or similar.

Comment: We usually associate "call" with "function", so people naturally turn "callable type" into "something function-like". But it's actually broader than that. Here's the description from cppreference (emphasis added): "Class template std::function is a general-purpose polymorphic function wrapper. Instances of std::function can **store, copy, and invoke** any CopyConstructible Callable target -- functions (via pointers thereto), lambda expressions, bind expressions, or other function objects, as well as pointers to member functions and **pointers to data members.**"

Comment: So, after `struct X { int i; }; X x; std::function<int> f(&X::i, x);`, calling `f()` returns the value of `x.i`. (caution: code written but not tested)

Comment: @PeteBecker `std::function<int>` is not valid.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I eventually figured out what syntax you meant, but it turns out not to be relevant because you're talking as if someone could pass a pointer-to-data-member and it would magically become wrapped in an std::function before the constraint checks it.  Of course that will not happen.  If the caller explicitly wraps a pointer-to-data-member in an std::function before passing that function to `X()`, there is nothing we can do to detect it using C++ language features.  If you have a better answer, please post it.

Comment: Sigh. The point is that `std:invocable` is defined in terms of callable types; pointer-to-data-member is a callable type, as the question clearly acknowledges. `std::invocable` will report that a pointer-to-data-member is invocable; the question is how to avoid that. This answer is simply wrong.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Finally I got your point.  Here's what you were trying to explain: https://godbolt.org/z/e75vxfqrr - I've edited my answer to deal with this.

Comment: Yeah, my bad; I only said that pointer-to-member-data is invocable three times; should have been clearer.